# Change bootstrap theme for rmdformats template

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-2, r-markdown

I tried the `html_clean` HTML output template for RMarkdown {[rmdformats](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats)} and I like it very much. (Here is a [sample output](https://rawgit.com/juba/rmdformats/master/inst/examples/html_clean/iris.html)). However I can't find a way to change the bootstrap theme to something else than `default`. (Nothing is mentioned in the documentation either). Specifying e.g. `theme: cerulean` in the YAML metadata block, causes the following error:

```
formal argument "theme" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I would be really grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `html_clean` function doesn't have a `theme` argument. All of the YAML metadata values must correspond to arguments to the function named in `output`.

There isn't any direct way to change this, but if you're feeling adventurous you can modify the package itself. Just add a `theme` parameter to `rmdformats::html_clean`, and then pass it along to `html_document_base` in place of `"default"` here:

https://github.com/juba/rmdformats/blob/f65d9c76b30e8ef47df2584b5c4890bc971254c4/R/html_clean.R#L157

Comment: Without being sure how to modify the package, i forked it and just changed "default" to "cerulean", in the aforementioned line. Then installed from "gd047/rmdformats" but nothing changed..